# Need help creating a kotlin js wrapper for mapbox-gl-draw

Tags: mapbox, kotlin-js

so i am trying to create a wrapper for mapbox-gl-draw in my kotlin react project.

my starter wrapper looks like this

```
@JsName("default")
external fun mapboxDraw()
```

i am trying to base it off of:

TS:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-draw/index.d.ts

JS:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/f1c3d595828880b383ec88403b849163cc376bc1/index.js

when i try and use it the browser keeps telling me

> mapBoxDraw is not a function

i eventually have to use it in kotlin js code based off this

```
type DrawControlProps = ConstructorParameters<typeof MapboxDraw>[0] & {
  position?: ControlPosition;

  onCreate?: (evt: {features: object[]}) => void;
  onUpdate?: (evt: {features: object[]; action: string}) => void;
  onDelete?: (evt: {features: object[]}) => void;
};

export default function DrawControl(props: DrawControlProps) {
  useControl<MapboxDraw>(
    () => new MapboxDraw(props),
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      map.on('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.on('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.on('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      map.off('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.off('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.off('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    {
      position: props.position
    }
  );

  return null;
}

DrawControl.defaultProps = {
  onCreate: () => {},
  onUpdate: () => {},
  onDelete: () => {}
};
```

but i need to get the mapboxdraw wrapper working first... What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is d.ts in the target library you can try automatic generation with [Dukat](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-external-declarations-with-dukat.html)

it seems to me that you forgot to specify in the file

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw")
@file:JsNonModule
```

I also see that the export is specified in the js code `export default MapboxDraw;`

And you have it like this: `external fun mapboxDraw()`

Worth changing to `external fun MapboxDraw()` or explicitly specify the name via an annotation